# Does calling "command.Execute" implicitly call CanExecute first?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands, canexecute

I just implemented a call of Execute for a Command without calling CanExecute first.

From debugging I would tell that CanExecute is called though; however, I'm not sure if this is coincidence.

I'd like to know if I can rely on the fact that CanExecute is implicitly called whenever I raise the Execute by hand, or if I should ensure calling CanExecute myself?

Comment: by default it is the responsibility of the command executor to verify id the command can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on that. `CanExecute()` is called when a `Command` is bound to a Command-enabled UI item like a Button (via the `CommandManager`) but checking `CanExecute()` in `Execute()` itself would be an implementation detail for a specific implementation of `ICommand` and is not implied.

However, it's an interesting idea and not a bad one considering how often I've had to do the following in my own code:

```
if (SomeCommand.CanExecute(null))
    SomeCommand.Execute(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't stop the command from execute if you just call the Execute method.
If you want to do so you should use:

```
if(myCommand.CanExecute())
{
    myCommand.Execute(); 
}
```

Or if you are using that command from binding you should raise myCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged when changing the corresponding properties.